# Why in the following UITableViewCell's method implementation we use static instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c

From the book Beginning iOS 6 development, ch 8, p.227.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = 
                @"SimpleTableIdentifier"; //why this string instance is   
                                          // static and what its purpose?

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = self.dwarves[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

"This string will be used as a key to represent the type of our table cell."

What's purpose of this instance?
 2. Why is it static?
 3. In the book is used term "instance". Are the terms "instances" and "vars" interchangable in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is made static so that it will only get set the first time we call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Subsequent calls to this method won't have to create a new local variable and set it every single time, since it's always the same.

Comment: thanks, I've understood it know. 
Could I ask one another here, what's the purpose of reuseIdentidier?

Comment: The reuse identifier tells your code which cell prototype to get from the storyboard. You can have multiple different prototypes in there because you might have different types of cells in your table view, because you might have a table that has different types of content in different cells. For example, you might have a table of media where they look different for the type (book, video, song, etc.). Each prototype cell needs its own reuse identifier.